# Error: Could not find or load main class in Textpad 8

Tags: java, classpath, textpad

I've been trying to get back into programming and I've been redoing some old labs. I'm setting up Textpad 8 so I can run java applications and it works fine until I add a package statement like so:

```
package pkg;

public class inPkg{
    public static void main(String args[]){
            System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

The file's location: C:\214\pkg\inPkg.java
When I compile everything is fine but when I try to run it, I get this error message:

*Error: Could not find or load main class inPkg*

*Tool completed with exit code 1*

Compile Java Tool:

Parameters: *javac -classpath "$FileDir;h:\214\;c:\214\;" $File*

Run Java Application Tool:

Parameters: *java -classpath "$FileDir;h:\214\;c:\214\;" $BaseName*

These tools are the only thing I changed in the configuration. The classpath have been written to follow the lab. instructions.

PS. Without the packages statement, the application runs perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Because probably you are not using the fully qualified class name when you do the java run. use

`java  -classpath 'your class path' pkg.inPkg`

Comment: So like, i have the file in C:\214\pkg\inPkg.java. Therefore, my parameter should be: java -classpath C:\214\pkg\inPkg?

Answer (score 0):

It will compile and execute correctly with following commands

```
C:\214>javac.exe pkg\inPkg.java
C:\214>java.exe pkg.inPkg
```

Note that the file location is `C:\214\pkg\inPkg.java`, however you execute the commands from `C:\214`